# How to make text fade to the left

Tags: html, css, styling

How can I make this work:

[image]

I am talking about the fading effect on the top left corner. How can I make the text that's on the left also invisible. I know it can be done via overflow: hidden. But how to make sure the text renders from the right?

I am asking a question about the part above the orange line (with that line included). The rest is to visually explain it.

This is my code:

```
  <div class="breadcrumbs">
    <div class="row breadcrumbs--row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <ul class="list--inline">
          <% @breadcrumbs.each_with_index do |(title, url), i| %>
            <li> <%= '>' if i > 0 %> <a class="breadcrumbs--title" href="<%= url %>" title="<%= title %>"><%= title %></a></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And my SCSS:

```
    .breadcrumbs {
        &--row {
            border-bottom: 2px solid #e2e2e2;
            margin-left: -20px;
            padding: {
                left: 15px;
                right: 15px;
                bottom: 10px;
            }

            width: calc(100% + 40px);
        }

        ul li {
            display: inline;
            a {
                text-decoration: none;
                padding-bottom: 6px;
            }

            &:last-child a {
                border-bottom: 4px solid $_blk_color-primary;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: pseudo element above with gradient

Comment: [Use `shadow-box` with `inset`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with :before pseudo-element:

```css
.container {
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:18px;
}
.faded {
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  margin-right:20px
}
.faded:before {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=1 );
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="faded">
    Some faded text
  </div>
  <div class="visible">
    Another text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I will try that first! Thanks, now I know what properties I can try! I will let you know :)

Comment: It works! Thank you, now I only need to figure out how to overflow the text from right to left, to make sure the text on the right is always visible

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you apply the `shadow` on the same element, it will look like the example, and css give the higher preference to the text than box-shadow.  You need to use another `div` to set the `shadow`.

the main thing to notice here is `.shadow` class and `position` on `.header` class.

```css
.block
{
  border:1px solid black;
  margin-left:100px;
  width:200px;   
  z-index:2;
}

.shadow
{
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:20px;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;  
  box-shadow: inset 20px 0px 50px white ;
}

.header
{  
  border:1px solid black;  
  padding:10px;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class='block'>
  <div class='header'> 
     <div class='shadow'>  
    </div>
    this is header with effect
  </div>
</div>
```